# MySqlBulkLoader from DataTable - VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, bulkinsert, bulkloader

I would like to import about 9.000.000 rows from an xml file to a MySql server. Currently I'm inserting the data rows by row, which is very slow. I'm able to upload about 50 rows / sec, which means it's gonna take days to complete. For another project I loaded similar data into a data table with 5000 rows at a time, and then i would bulk insert all 5000 rows at once. This made me reach about 7.500 rows / sec. Problem is that was with an SQL server, and this is MySQL. I can't find any one using the MySqlBulkLoader class from a data table. Is this possible and how would i go about doing it?

Example of first 750 elemets in the xml file: http://view.qrdetector.dk/test.xml

These are the columns i need in my database from the xml file.

```
    'Create datatable to hold the information from the XML file
    Dim ReadXML_DT As New DataTable
    ReadXML_DT.Columns.Add("KoeretoejIdent", GetType(String))
    ReadXML_DT.Columns.Add("KoeretoejArtNavn", GetType(String))
    ReadXML_DT.Columns.Add("KoeretoejAnvendelseNavn", GetType(String))
    ReadXML_DT.Columns.Add("RegistreringNummerNummer", GetType(String))
    ReadXML_DT.Columns.Add("KoeretoejOplysningStatus", GetType(String))
    ReadXML_DT.Columns.Add("KoeretoejOplysningFoersteRegistreringDato", GetType(String))
    ReadXML_DT.Columns.Add("KoeretoejOplysningStelNummer", GetType(String))
    ReadXML_DT.Columns.Add("KoeretoejMaerkeTypeNavn", GetType(String))
    ReadXML_DT.Columns.Add("KoeretoejModelTypeNavn", GetType(String))
    ReadXML_DT.Columns.Add("KoeretoejVariantTypeNavn", GetType(String))
    ReadXML_DT.Columns.Add("DrivkraftTypeNavn", GetType(String))
    ReadXML_DT.Columns.Add("SynResultatSynsType", GetType(String))
    ReadXML_DT.Columns.Add("SynResultatSynsDato", GetType(String))
    ReadXML_DT.Columns.Add("SynResultatSynStatusDato", GetType(String))
    ReadXML_DT.Columns.Add("SidsteSynTjek", GetType(String))
```

I've manually made a the CSV file with 130.000 rows with the 15 colums I need. Then I used the bulk insert code from Plutonix's reply. I'm now able to parse the 130.000 rows in about 215 sec, which gives me an average speed of about 600 rows / sec. This is pretty much the same result as before. Is this because of my connection to the MySQL server?

```
Dim sw As Stopwatch = New Stopwatch
sw.Start()

' Finally, BulkLoad
Dim cols As String() = {"KoeretoejIdent", "KoeretoejArtNavn", "KoeretoejAnvendelseNavn", "RegistreringNummerNummer", "KoeretoejOplysningStatus", "KoeretoejOplysningFoersteRegistreringDato", "KoeretoejOplysningStelNummer", "KoeretoejMaerkeTypeNavn", "KoeretoejModelTypeNavn", "KoeretoejVariantTypeNavn", "DrivkraftTypeNavn", "SynResultatSynsType", "SynResultatSynsDato", "SynResultatSynStatusDato", "SidsteSynTjek"}
Dim rows As Integer = 0
Using dbcon As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim bulk = New MySqlBulkLoader(dbcon)

    bulk.TableName = "synsbasen_testLoad"
    bulk.FieldTerminator = "^"
    bulk.LineTerminator = "\r\n"    ' == CR/LF
    bulk.FileName = "C:/Users/Synsbasen/Desktop/abc.csv"         ' full file path name to CSV 
    bulk.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1    ' has a header (default)

    bulk.Columns.Clear()
    For Each s In cols
        bulk.Columns.Add(s)         ' specify col order in file
    Next

    rows = bulk.Load()
End Using
sw.Stop()
' SW is a stopwatch
MsgBox(rows & "rows converted and loaded in " & sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds & " secs")
```

Comment: Do all the columns go into the db?  `MySqlBulkLoader` probably isnt the answer

Comment: No the xml is much more detailed than what i need. The xml file got about 50 columns, i only want about 15 of those coulmns. I used to cut out the elements i needed and i would temporarily store 5.000 rows in a data table. Then i would use SqlBulkCopy to insert all rows at once. I cant use this command with a MySQL server, so what is my alernative

Comment: I think the fastest thing would be in several steps. With that many rows I would try to work out an IEnumerable solution and avoid loading the column data you dont need.  What does the first few lines of the XML look like?

Comment: As it appears that MySqlBulkLoader is designed to load a CSV, why not just prepare a temporary CSV as the intermediate step instead of the DataTable?

Comment: @Plutonix The xml-file is close to 60GB, but i've made a small sample of the first 750 elements of the xml file here: http://view.qrdetector.dk/test.xml You should be able to see everything you need!

Comment: @TnTinMn Thanks for your response: I actually just tried this. I'm loading 5000 rows into a CSV file and then i use the MySQL command: "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE". This increased my speed from 50 rows / sec to about 525 rows / sec, which is much better, but I'm still looking at 6-7 hours of uploading, which i need to run once a week.

Comment: You'll probably have to change the code in the answer since there is a namespace involved, but the gist should be the same.

Comment: 600 r/sec is much faster than the 50 r/sec originally posted, so there is some improvement - probably due to getting rid of the DT.  The CSV-only import looks correct but if one of those `Koeretoe` is something like the entire text for an article or something, then you will loose performance there due to much (much) more data being transferred.  That could easily be tested.  You could also try to import at the server.  There is obviously a lot we dont know.

Comment: I don't work with MySql, but I came across this option: [Compress network communication between client and server](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/compress-network-communication-between-client-and-server/) and thought it may be of benefit to your usage case.

Comment: @TnTinMn Thank you! That also made a huge improvement. Adding the 'UseCompression=True;' to my connection string made my avg speed jump from 500-600 rows/sec to about 1600-1700 rows/sec. Now im able to process the entire 60 GB xml file in about 1,5 hour!

Comment: Tobias, I'm glad that helped.  However, I suspect that you can do better as I would bet that the xml parsing is a significant part of the processing time.  1) Are you still limiting yourself to a batch size of 5000? Up that to 100000. 2) Is the operation Read Xml->Write file->Send->repeat until done? If so, consider putting the first two steps into a parallel task that pushed the filenames onto a queue for sending.

Comment: @TnTinMn, I made some tests to figure out where the time was being used. Turns out you're right and about 80% of the process time was me opening and appending to the CSV file. I implemented a StringBuilder instead of appending each row to the CSV one by one, which drastically increased the speed again. I also did some tests with the bulk size and found that i max at about 20.000 rows / batch. With the new bulk size and the StringBuilder i achieved speeds between 9.000-10.000 rows / sec and I'm now able to process the entire file in about 15 min! Thank you so much for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will read in one million rows from XML, extract a subset of the data, export to CSV (using CSVHelper), then load them to MySql using `MySqlBulkLoader` in about 30 seconds.

```vb
' IEnumerable of the data parts to import
Dim recList As IEnumerable(Of SmSample)

' load some columns as a class
Using fs As FileStream = File.OpenRead(XMLFile)
    Dim xDoc = XDocument.Load(fs)

    ' its IEnumerable - leave it that way
    recList = xDoc.Descendants("Sample").
               Select(Function(j) New SmSample With {.Name = j.Element("Name").Value,
                                 .Descr = j.Element("Descr").Value,
                                 .Price = Decimal.Parse(j.Element("Price").Value),
                                 .ItemDate = DateTime.Parse(j.Element("ItemDate").Value)
                                                    }
                      )
End Using

' Have CSVHelper write them out
' this is the most time consuming part what with Disk IO and all
Using strW As New StreamWriter(CSVFile)
    Using csv As New CsvWriter(strW)

        ' ToDo: add other things like Field separators etc
        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(Of SmSample.CSVItemMap)()

        csv.WriteRecords(recList)
    End Using
End Using

' Finally, BulkLoad
Dim cols As String() = {"Name", "Descr", "Price", "ItemDate"}
Dim rows As Int32 = 0
Using dbcon As New MySqlConnection(MySQLConnStr)
    Dim bulk = New MySqlBulkLoader(dbcon)

    bulk.TableName = "Sample"
    bulk.FieldTerminator = ","
    bulk.LineTerminator = "\r\n"    ' == CR/LF
    bulk.FileName = CSVFile         ' full file path name to CSV 
    bulk.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1    ' has a header (default)

    bulk.Columns.Clear()
    For Each s In cols
        bulk.Columns.Add(s)         ' specify col order in file
    Next

    rows = bulk.Load()
End Using

' SW is a stopwatch
Console.WriteLine("{0} rows converted and loaded in {1} secs", 
                          rows, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000)
```

Yours will take longer naturally, but 1,000,000 rows is already kind of large, so it should scale decently enough. If you wanted to load them in batches use something like 500k. It would be easy to write the CSV in parts using `Skip()` and `Take()`.

The interim steps took 9 secs to select the parts from the XML, 15 secs to write the CSV, 7 secs for MySQL to load the data.

The specifics of your XML file are a mystery (the link was added to the question well after this was posted).  Since you can load it to a `DataTable`, the test just used the result of `myDT.WriteXml(...)`, so you may have to change that part.  Leave it as a linq query and let `CSVHelper` consume it since the applet itself doesn't need the collection data at all.

The only "trick" was to format the `DateTime` field so MySQL could parse it:

```vb
Public Class CSVItemMap
    Inherits CsvClassMap(Of SmSample)

    Public Sub New()
        AutoMap()
        Map(Function(m) m.ItemDate).TypeConverterOption("yyyy-MM-dd")
    End Sub

End Class
```

[CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) is very cool, very powerful and integral to the results.

`SmSample` is just a class with the properties shown which is the desired columns from the larger XML data.  Its roles are to a) shed the extraneous columns you don't need/want as soon as possible and b) provide the 'holder' for the data for CSVHelper to act upon.

The answer also uses the built in `MySqlBulkLoader` tool which I find easier to use than the SQL `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` form.

Comment: I've uploaded a test XML file if you would like to see the structure of the XML file: There is a link in the comments above: I've included the rows i want to save from the xml file aswel in the question description incase you need any of the information! Thank you so much for you response. I'm going to use it as a template and come back with the results!

Comment: You are going to have to rework the XML extractor part since yours has a namespace.  It may just be a matter of prepending it: `xDoc.Descendants(theNC & "Sample")`.

Comment: I've updated my question and tested your BulkLoad code. I'm still not able to parse faster than 600 rows / sec and not the 1.000.000 in less than a minute - you said you achieved with the same code. Is this because of my connection speed to the server?